# How to backup apps + data using TitaniumBackup directly to SMB share

Tags: linux, backup, mount, android, nfs

I've been searching for answer to this question for quite some time now and finally decided I should as a question here.

So I've managed to find a kernel module (cifs.ko) for my kernel build on xda-developers forum/site.
Then I ssh to my phone (GT-I9300) and as root issue

```
insmod cifs.ko
```

The module loads correctly. I can mount SMB shares using command

```
mount -t cifs -o username=login,password=secret //ip.address.goes.here/sharename /mount/point/goes/here
```

and this mounts correctly.
Then I can cd into mounted directory and create, modify, delete, rename files/directories.

But when I start TitaniumBackup and change backup directory location to mounted folder and try to backup any application I get error "insufficient free storage space". Now how I could mount my share (I can host it as scp,sftp,ftp,smb,nfs,webdav) ?

I also tried using busybox to mount nfs share but I cannot find nfs.ko for my kernel and when I try to mount my share using busybox (or normal) I get an error that the device doesn't exist.

What I want to achieve is to backup my apps + data directly to my NAS instead of doing it locally first and then copying backups to my NAS.

Please help.

Comment: Do you see any new files created by TitaniumBackup and what are their sizes? Also tell us the output of 'mount' and 'df'

Comment: Open a ticket at the titanium bug-tracker and ask for this feature (titanium read/write to samba shares).

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин: Yeah. It seems that I have to do that to get working what I need. Pity that this wasn't included in the first place. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Cray: No. I just left the topic and moved on. Got new phone which is still unrooted so I cannot use TB to backup data. Only helium can be used to do app backup. Maybe when I will have rooted phone.

Comment: What's the status of this in 2020 ?

Comment: Same. Nothing changed. Just dropped TB in favor of Helium which doesn't require root. But I do miss TB. It has great features which I certainly would use. But since I don't have rooted phone now I cannot use it.